# Alter required attribute for customer attribute

Tags: attributes, customer, magento-2.0

I am migrating customers from Mage 1 to Mage 2.

The mage 1 instance did not require first name and last name (it was used as a back end repository for a mobile app).

When I am importing the customers it is telling me that first name and last name are required.

I know that in mage 1 I was able to alter a property and set required to false.

I am unsure on how to do this in mage 2.

Ideally I would like to set to false, do the import and then set to true when the script is finished.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see the table looks the same from 1.9.x

`UPDATE eav_attribute SET is_required = 0 WHERE attribute_code = 'lastname'`

It might still work. Backup and try it.

Comment: I was hoping for a magento way but this works, will try today.